# mysql ошибка в workbench

Tags: mysql

Я установил mysql на macbook и workbench получаю ошибку:

> Your connection attempt failed for user 'root' from your host to server at 127.0.0.1:3306:
>     Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
>
> Please:
>   1 Check that mysql is running on server 127.0.0.1
>   2 Check that mysql is running on port 3306 (note: 3306 is the default, but this can be changed)
>   3 Check the root has rights to connect to 127.0.0.1 from your address (mysql rights define what clients can connect to the server and from which machines)
>   4 Make sure you are both providing a password if needed and using the correct password for 127.0.0.1 connecting from the host address you're connecting from

Я просто создал соединение с именем root без пароля, так как не было поля для пароля, сначала я установил просто workbench и создал это подключение root без пароля, но не мог создавать ничего в базе даных была красная строка слева not connections. Потом я установил connection community и сервер running, но теперь получаю ошибку...

Comment: А как устанавливали MySQL-сервер? Судя по ошибке с высокой долей вероятности он просто не запущен. Посмотрите есть ли он в списке задач через Мониторинг системы или команду ps aux | grep mysqld

Comment: Access denied это ответ MySQL, так что сервер запущен

Answer (score 2, accepted):

если вы создавали рута без указания хоста, то по умолчанию у вас создан 'root'@'%' и с локальной машины вы под ним зайти не можете.

вам нужно создать root@localhost

если не можете зайти в mysql, чтобы создать пользователя, то это можно сделать через режим skip-grant-tables,
подробности см [MySQL error 1045](http://sqlinfo.ru/articles/info/16.html)